# Transact-SQL local variable with case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables, case

Given this simple example:

```
DECLARE @aux INT
SET @aux = NULL

SELECT
CASE WHEN @aux = NULL THEN 'null' ELSE 'not null' END AS ETest,
CASE WHEN @aux <> NULL THEN 'not null' ELSE 'null' END AS ITest;
```

I was expecting result : ETEST null, ITEST NULL, apparently this is wrong, and I need a hint to find where my logic fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use operators as `<>` and `=` to verify `null` values. You have to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`  as below

```
DECLARE @aux INT
SET @aux = NULL

SELECT
CASE WHEN @aux IS NULL THEN 'null' ELSE 'not null' END AS ETest,
CASE WHEN @aux IS NOT NULL THEN 'not null' ELSE 'null' END AS ITest;
```